# unordered_map with custom hashing/equal functions - functions don't get called

Tags: c++, c++11

This is weird.. the following code (which I managed to compile thanks to [Cassio Neri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137388/cassio-neri)) is compiling without any error.. by the way either hashing_func nor key_equal_func do get called (the couts aren't showing in the console window)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

unsigned long hashing_func(string key)
{
    cout << "Hashing called";
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<key.size(); i++)
    {
        hash += (71*hash + key[i]) % 5;
    }
    return hash;
}

template<class T> bool key_equal_fn(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 == t2;
}

template <> bool key_equal_fn<string>(string t1, string t2)
{
    cout << "Equal called";
    return !(t1.compare(t2));
}

int main ()
{
    unordered_map<string, string>::size_type n = 5;
    unordered_map<string, string> mymap(n, (const std::hash<string> &)hashing_func, 
        (const std::equal_to<string> &)(function<bool(string,string)>(key_equal_fn<string>))) ;

    bool case_insensitive = mymap.key_eq()("test","TEST");

    mymap["paul"] = "jenna";
    mymap["frank"] = "ashley";

    if(mymap["paul"] == mymap["frank"])
        cout << "equal" << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MSVC2012, any hint on what could be the problem?

Comment: You're still making the same mistakes as in you other question. Take a look at my solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809087/unordered-map-constructor-error-equal-to-templated-function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you need to pass the types of your hash function and hash_key_equal function to your unordered_map, and then the actual functions to the ctor of the map.

Your unordered_map definition should look like this:

```
unordered_map<
    std::string,
    std::string,
    std::function<unsigned long(std::string)>,
    std::function<bool(std::string, std::string)>
> mymap(n, hashing_func, key_equal_fn<std::string>);
```

The `unordered_map` is a template and it looks like this:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>
> class unordered_map;
```

which means if you want to pass new `Hash` and `KeyEqual` functions you have to tell the template the types of these things.

Link isn't accessible anymore (Request Update):
[Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3rODqP$4)

Comment: Got it: the templated function had default parameters.. functions can deduce templated parameters from their arguments but if I don't specify them I might use default ones and get errors. Thank you Tony!! This wasn't an easy catch in my opinion!!

Comment: What the meaning of the parameter `n`? Size of hash-table?

Answer (score 23):

You have to specify hash/compare functions with template arguments, not in the constructor. Here is an example:

```
class Hasher
{
public:
  size_t operator() (string const& key) const
  {
      cout << "Hashing called";
      size_t hash = 0;
      for(size_t i=0; i<key.size(); i++)
      {
          hash += (71*hash + key[i]) % 5;
      }
      return hash;
  }
};
class EqualFn
{
public:
  bool operator() (string const& t1, string const& t2) const
  {
    cout << "Equal called";
    return !(t1.compare(t2));
  }
};

unordered_map<string, string, Hasher, EqualFn> mymap(5);
```

Comment: is there no way to pass a function pointer instead of these hasher functors which cause half a dozen lines of garbage boilerplate