# hashmap for 2d(3d) coordinates (i.e. vector of doubles)?

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, hashmap

I wonder if there is a general all-around solution for a `hash map` for coordinates (in 2d or 3d, i.e. a vector of doubles)?

An example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222143/unordered-map-hash-function-c/7222212#7222212) demonstrates how to create a custom hash-map for `pair<int,int>`, 
but it does not seem to be trivial to come-up with an unique map from `pair<double,double>` (which could represent a 2d coordinate) to `size_t`.

I know that i can use ordered maps by providing comparator object, but for my application there is no need to order them and hash-maps seems to be faster anyway. 
However since i'm a newcomer to all this `hash` stuff, i am kind of lost on how to proceed.

p/s/ i use c++11.

Comment: Why can't you use the same approach in the link you provided? It seems trivial to use `pair<double,double>` instead of `pair<int,int>`, and since you don't need ordering you can still use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @André because the map is not unique.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you cannot have multiple equal keys in the `std::unordered_map`. You can however have different keys map to the same value. So, the keys themselves are unique. Could you describe your problem a little bit better?

Comment: Frankly, i don't yet have a problem. I just assumed that the map should be unique, therefore mapping `(double)*100+(double)` to `int`  is not unique. But maybe that's all right. As i said, i'm a newcomer to hash stuff.

Comment: you are correct, the hash should be unique and you should devise a way to avoid collisions depending on your data ranges, or use a good hashing method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid extra dependencies, you can use [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). Here's an example using the code from the link you posted, and updated to use a `std::pair<double,double>`:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class TPoint3D{
public:
    TPoint3D(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z){};

    double x, y, z;
};

struct hashFunc{
    size_t operator()(const TPoint3D &k) const{
    size_t h1 = std::hash<double>()(k.x);
    size_t h2 = std::hash<double>()(k.y);
    size_t h3 = std::hash<double>()(k.z);
    return (h1 ^ (h2 << 1)) ^ h3;
    }
};

struct equalsFunc{
  bool operator()( const TPoint3D& lhs, const TPoint3D& rhs ) const{
    return (lhs.x == rhs.x) && (lhs.y == rhs.y) && (lhs.z == rhs.z);
  }
};

typedef unordered_map<TPoint3D, int, hashFunc, equalsFunc> TPoint3DMap;

int main(){
  TPoint3DMap myMap;

  // test equalsFunc
  myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 20.0, 30.0)] = 100;
  myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 20.0, 30.0)] = 200;

  assert(myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 20.0, 30.0)] == 200);

  // test if hashFunc handles well repeated values inside TPoint3D
  myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 10.0, 10.0)] = 1;
  myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 20.0, 10.0)] = 2;
  myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 10.0, 20.0)] = 3;
  myMap[TPoint3D(20.0, 10.0, 10.0)] = 4;

  assert(myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 10.0, 10.0)] == 1);
  assert(myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 20.0, 10.0)] == 2);
  assert(myMap[TPoint3D(10.0, 10.0, 20.0)] == 3);
  assert(myMap[TPoint3D(20.0, 10.0, 10.0)] == 4);

  return 0;
}
```

As I said before, if you wish to use another structure you have to adapt both the `pairHash` class and `pairEquals` struct  `operator()` to appropriately hash and compare the new keys, respectively.

Cheers

**EDIT :**

- Modified code to use custom TPPoint3D class and uniform functor classes definitions (both using struct).
- Added simple tests to validate the hash and equals functors.

Comment: thanks for reply, that's probably what i was looking for. What would be the best extension to 3D: `(h1^(h2<<1))^h3` ?

Comment: @Denis: Yes, I think that would work. However, I think @Timothy Shields' solution is more elegant and easily extensible. I didn't know myself that `std::tuple<>` already defined equality and compare functions automatically. You just have to create your map of tuples and it will just work for 2D, 3D, ..., nD :) Still, attention to the fact Timothy mentioned that the lookup must be _exact_, which means all the items in the tuple must be _exactly_ the same (value) for the keys to be considered equal and for the map to work as you expect.

Comment: @AndreNevas thanks for reply. Maybe i miss something, but i don't see how could i apply his solution to an arbitrary given class (other than std::tuple).

Comment: @Denis: what he says is that `std::tuple` automatically uses the equality and hash functions of the types _it contains_ to perform the equality and hash functions of the tuple _itself_ **as a whole**. If you use a custom class as an element of the tuple, you will have to provide the equality and hash functions yourself for that class, I guess. For `double` though (which is what we thought you needed), `std::tuple` will work out of the box since it's a built in type.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, my custom class is actually something like `class TPoint()` which, say, has `point.x` and `point.y`. So i want to use it. I can easily use it in `std::map`, but i though of moving to `unordered_map` instead, if i can make it work.

Comment: In that case I think you will have to define your own hash and compare functions as mentioned in my solution. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15809592/1921751) you have other ways to define these functions.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot comment on Andre's answer because I do not have enough reputation yet, but anyone trying to create a hash function using ^ (XOR) should note that XOR is associative. In other words `a ^ (b ^ c) == (a ^ b) ^ c`. This means that

```
(h1 ^ (h2 << 1)) ^ h3
```

which is the return value of Andre's answer, is the same as:

```
h1 ^ ((h2 << 1) ^ h3)
```

which itself is, due to the commutative nature of XOR (`a ^ b == b ^ a`), equivalent to:

```
(h3 ^ (h2 << 1)) ^ h1
```

What all of this means is that the hash method I am referring to will, for distinct `a`, `b`, and `c`, return the same hash for `(a,b,c)` as it will for `(c,b,a)`. In other words the x and z coordinates are order independent / insensitive.

Depending on how you are using this hash method this might not be a problem. However, if for example the points you were hashing were aligned to a grid you would receive an inordinate number of hash collisions.

I would replace the expression in the return statement in Andre's answer with the one below. This should be order dependent / sensitive.

```
(h1 ^ (h2 << 1)) ^ (h3 << 2)
```

Comment: i don't see how `int hashFunc(int h1,int h2,int h3){return h1 ^ (h2<<1) ^ (h3<<2);}` would work as a hash function either. cause `hash(4,0,0) = 4`, `hash(0,2,0) = 4`, `hash(0,0,1) = 4`, `hash(4,2,1) = 4` etc... so there's many coords (in a shifted/xor'd pattern) that will give the same hash.

Answer (score 2):

In the 3D case,`std::unordered_map<std::tuple<double, double, double>, your_value_type>` should work fine for you, *assuming you are doing exact lookups*. `std::tuple<...>` defines equality and hash functions for you, based on the equality and hash functions of the types it is aggregating.

The 2D case is of course the same, but using a `std::tuple<double, double>`.

**Edit:** Sorry for misinformation. There actually is not a default hash defined for `std::tuple`. To use this approach, you would have to define a `hash_tuple` templated functor class and then use that in the `std::unordered_map`. Other answers show how to do that part.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can one look at implemented hash for touple, or is this information not disclosed? I'm apply this to already written class in third-party library, so i would prefer not to use std::tuple.

Comment: This is the best solution presented so far and you will essentially only need one line to define your entire data structure.

Comment: @TimothyShields tried your solution in another context, it seems hash is not provided by default: `static assertion failed: std::hash is not specialized for this type`, at least for `std::unordered_map<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int>,double >`

Comment: @Denis Yeah, I've learned the same thing since. Only comparisons are provided for tuples. Defining a hash_tuple templates functor and using that won't be hard though. Other answers suggest how to implement the hash.

Comment: @TimothyShields sure, it's not hard to implement. I actually used the first answer, but just wanted to be sure that i didn't overlook something and there is indeed no default hash for tuples

Answer (score 1):

What about using `hash_combine` from Boost?

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html