# `std::unordered_map` without duplicating key data

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, stdmap

I have a `Person` class, which has a `name` property (`std::string`).

I want to create a lookup-table, a `std::unordered_map`, so I can find a `Person` by their name. However, given a `Person`, I also want to be able to get their name.

This necessitates storing the `name` twice - once as the key of the map, and once inside the person object, as shown in my code below.

Since I have many `Person`s loaded into memory at once, I don't want the overhead of storing their names twice.

I've tried using references/pointers to the keys instead inside the `Person` class, but this creates problems as the map seems to reshuffle its data when it is modified, and the references become invalid.

I've also tried using `std::unordered_set`, but this means I need to construct a whole `Person` object every time I want to perform a lookup.

Is there any way for the key and value of a unordered map to share the same data?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>


class Person
{
    private:
        const std::string _name;

    public:
        Person( const std::string& name ) : _name( name )
        {
        }


        const std::string& get_name() const
        {
            return _name;
        }
};


int main()
{
    auto my_set = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Person>>();

    my_set.insert( { "alice", std::shared_ptr<Person>( new Person( "alice" )) } );
    my_set.insert( { "bob", std::shared_ptr<Person>( new Person( "bob" )) } );
    my_set.insert( { "charlie", std::shared_ptr<Person>( new Person( "charlie" )) } );

    std::cout << my_set.find( "bob" )->second->get_name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to store `name` inside `Person`?

Comment: In this hypothetical example, no, but assume I do.

Comment: @cz - Why not use an unordered set with a custom hasher instead? This seems to be what you are after anyway.

Comment: You could also use a sorted vector.

Comment: Just use `Boost.Multiindex` - despite it's name you can use it for one index only, and most probably you would need more indexes anyway.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: That's a bad choice if you ever need to insert persons into that sorted vector. Basically, filling such a vector person by person is O(n^2) due to the required shifting.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy then OP just can use `std::set` with c++14, but that's different O(n)

Comment: Unless the person object is large, using `unordered_set` is probably your best bet here. It's space efficient, still O(1). Default constructing a few fields, including things like vectors and strings, is very cheap.

Comment: "I've tried using references/pointers to the keys instead inside the Person class, but this creates problems as the map seems to reshuffle its data when it is modified" – actually, ``unordered_map`` has reference stability, so unless you erase the very entry you're pointing to, you should be good to go. Maybe you can clarify what you did, exactly.

Comment: I guess your pointer doesn't point inside the ``unordered_map`` but a temporary object on the stack. You should only set rsp. update it after the ``insert()`` rsp. ``emplace()``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `std::set`, you might use *transparent* comparer (`std::unordered_set` doesn't seems to support that :/ ):

```
struct LessPerson
{
    using is_transparent = void; // enable "transparent" comparer

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    bool operator ()(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) const
    {
        // Compare only "name".
        return toString(t1) < toString(t2);
    }

    // trivial one
    const std::string& toString(const std::string& s) const
    {
        return s;
    }

    // the one why we create the class
    const std::string& toString(const Person& p) const
    {
        return p.get_name();
    }

    // A tricky one to handle dereference of (smart) pointers.
    template <typename T,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Person, std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>>::value>* = nullptr>
    const std::string& toString(const T& p) const
    {
        return (*p).get_name();
    }

};
```

And then use it:

```
auto my_set = std::set<std::shared_ptr<Person>, LessPerson>();

my_set.insert( { std::make_shared<Person>("alice") } );
my_set.insert( { std::make_shared<Person>("bob") } );
my_set.insert( { std::make_shared<Person>("charlie") } );

auto it = my_set.find("bob"); // search using "bob" directly without creating a new Person
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c831c9b5bc2b941)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Boost.Multi-index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) for this purpose. Though there is a learning curve for this library you will find it very usable very fast. So for your case:

```
namespace mpi = boost::multi_index;
boost::multi_index_container<
        Person,
        mpi::indexed_by<
           mpi::hashed_unique< mpi::const_mem_fun< Person, const std::string &, &Person::get_name > >
        >
> my_set;
```

Now you can use it as hashed set with a string key:

```
auto f = my_set.find( "bob" );
if( f != my_set.end() )
    std::cout << f->get_name() << std::endl;
```

This may look like a bit overkill, but you will see full power of this library when you start to add more members to the class `Person` you will need to provide different index to access them by that member. Let's say you added a phone number which is also unique (method `const std::string &get_phone() const`):

```
boost::multi_index_container<
        Person,
        mpi::indexed_by<
           mpi::hashed_unique< mpi::const_mem_fun< Person, const std::string &, &Person::get_name >,
           mpi::hashed_unique< mpi::const_mem_fun< Person, const std::string &, &Person::get_phone >>
        >
> my_set;

// lookup by phone:

const auto &idx = boost::get<1>( my_set );
auto f = idx.find( "1234567890" );
if( f != my_set.end() )
    std::cout << f->get_name() << std::endl;
```

Note: you can change stored data as a shared pointer instead of storing by value of course, I just omitted that for example simplicity.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if this will end up using less space than the simple `unordered_map` solution. A string is often 3-4 words in size, so that would imply that the overhead of multi_index is less than 4N or so where N is the number of entries.

Comment: @NirFriedman I doubt that OPs main concern is actual space, bigger problem  of data duplication as that creates bugs in the program - in his example it is easy to store person with different name than key for example.

Comment: While it may seem improbable to you... you can't just flat out second guess questions for absolutely no reason. Direct quote:  "Since I have many Persons loaded into memory at once, I don't want the overhead of storing their names twice.".

Comment: @NirFriedman you assumed that overhead in the question means memory overhead, but that is not mandatory true, is it? There are multiple overheads in this approach and memory only one of them.

Comment: The "data duplication" "bug overhead" is not proportional to the number of Persons being created, so to say OP was talking about some kind of other overhead in that quote is dubious at best. In the time you've spent arguing with me you could have written a trivial 10 line allocator that will show much memory is being used, and improved your answer considerably instead.

Comment: @NirFriedman creating one instance of Person for lookup in `std::unordered_set` is also not proportional to the number of Persons being created. Why OP has concern about that? For allocator, it does not make sense to measure memory consumption of hypothetical example.

Comment: Because, they clearly don't *only* care about space, but also performance. But the question was *very* clearly asking how to improve memory usage when many `Person` objects are involved, and it's not even clear if your answer does that. If you want to put in the 5 minutes required to verify whether your answer actually does improve space usage, would be great, but I won't continue to logic chop with you.

Comment: @NirFriedman the first definition of `my_set` by @Slava (i.e. that with just one index) takes the same memory as a `std::unordered_set<Person>`, so, yes, this is memory efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If your "persons" are never copied or moved, and their names are never copied or moved, you can use a pointer to `string` instead of `string` as your key. This requires using a custom `hash` and `equal` functors.

```
struct myhash
{
    unsigned operator()(std::string* s) const
    {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(*s);
    }
};

struct myequal
{
    unsigned operator()(std::string* s1, std::string* s2) const
    {
        return *s1 == *s2;
    }
};
...
auto my_set = std::unordered_map<std::string*, std::shared_ptr<Person>, myhash, myequal>();
```

This also complicates lookup a bit: you have to lookup a pointer to `string`.

```
std::string b = "bob";
std::cout << my_set.find(&b)->second->get_name() << std::endl;
```

Here it is impossible to have the string `bob` inline, because your code has to get a pointer to it.

Comment: The shortcoming you mention could probably be removed by simply using `reference_wrapper<const std::string>` as the key instead.

Comment: @Nir Friedman Nope. Second the call to .find with an rvalue would not be possible and first when copying object and reference, the reference_wrapper is simply duplicated and the object is copied, the reference in the wrapper still pointing to the original string.

Comment: @DrSvanHay You're right, since they delete that overload, but it would be trivial to write something yourself that has the correct behavior. I don't understand your second point at all, it has the same behavior on copy as a pointer which is what the answer uses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really struggling with memory you should use `boost::flat_set`.
It has very low memory overhead, the only problem is that if you update your set of persons it has horrible performance.  If you just create and never modify it performance is worse than `unordered_` but not terrible.

In case you insist on using `unordered_map` I think you need to use unordered_multiset since I see no point in having your class using just one field to determine if 2 instances are equal.
This is possible, but [very ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809087/unordered-map-constructor-error-equal-to-templated-function), you need to define your own hashing and equality functions.

Another simpler but more error prone solution is to use hash as a key like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Person {

public:
    Person(const std::string& name, const int age) : name_(name), age_(age) {}
public:
    const std::string& name() const { return name_; }
    int age() const { return age_; }
private:
    std::string name_;
    int age_;
};

int main()
{
    Person p1("Joe", 11), p2("Jane", 22), p3("James", 33), p4("Joe", 44);
    std::unordered_multimap<size_t, Person> persons{ {std::hash<std::string>()(p1.name()), p1}, {std::hash<std::string>()(p2.name()), p2},{std::hash<std::string>()(p3.name()), p3}, {std::hash<std::string>()(p4.name()), p4} };
    auto potential_joes = persons.equal_range(std::hash<std::string>()("Joe"));
    for (auto it = potential_joes.first; it != potential_joes.second; ++it) {
        if (it->second.name() == "Joe") {
            std::cout << it->second.name() << " is " << it->second.age() << " years old" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I would use this only if your strings are long, you actually measured memory usage and you are uncomfortable with writing custom comparators.
As you see from code you are reimplemening a lot of `unordred_map` logic yourself, and it is easy to mess up.

**important note**
If your key depends on your value in the map you must be sure not to modify value.
So for example in the code I posted you should probably make member `name_` `const` and comment why it is `const`.