# how to make custom type work as keys in unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to get customized hash table working on custom types. 
Referring to [unordered_map constructor error (equal_to templated function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809087/unordered-map-constructor-error-equal-to-templated-function)

I have:

```
typedef pair<int, int> tCoord;
struct hashing_func {
    unsigned long operator()(const tCoord& key) const {
        unsigned long hash = 0;
        int h1 = key.first;
        int h2 = key.second;
        return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);

    }
};

struct key_equal_fn {
    bool operator()(const tCoord& t1, const tCoord& t2) const {
        return t1.first == t2.first && t1.second == t2.second;
    }
};

unordered_map<tCoord, int, hashing_func, key_equal_fn> coord2cnt;
unordered_map<tCoord, int, hashing_func, key_equal_fn>::iterator iter;
iter = coord2cnt.find(coord);
```

This snippet didn't compile and complained about missing function call to find():

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
```

Also tried to use it as `coord2cnt[coord]`, but also got errors on missing `[]` operator.

I'm compiling using g++ 4.2, which is a bit old, but was fine compiling the following (from the above link):

```
typedef unordered_map<string, string, hashing_func, key_equal_fn> MapType;
MapType::size_type n = 5;
MapType mymap(n, hashing_func(), key_equal_fn());
```

Also wonder why this type of definition would work, i.e., specifying 5 in the first parameter. This way of definition seems to be missing in the unordered_map API??

Anyone knows what went wrong here?
Thanks!

UPDATE: as pointed out, string is an internal class that has a built-in hash function available. So I rephrased the question to use a customized type here.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f362919bb753ddbb

Answer (score 0):

An unordered_map for string as key is handled internally. You don't have to define hash functions for string as keys.

If you want to pass a class or structure as a key. Then you have to define a hash function for it to calculate hash index for keys where collisions are minimum. To find the structure or class object using .find, overload bool operator == in the structure or class that you are using.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> myMap;
  myMap.insert({"asd", 1});
  myMap.insert({"qwe", 2});
  std::string input;
  std::cout<<"Enter String: ";
  std::cin>>input;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it = myMap.find(input);

  if(it != myMap.end())
    std::cout<<"Found";
  else
    std::cout<<"Not Found";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your custom type of function "key_equal_fn" is [string, string],
which is not match with "text2cnt"

If you want do it in a fully-specialized template way,how about this:

```
template <typename T>
struct key_equal_fn {
    bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2) const {
        return t1==t2;
    }
};

template<>
struct key_equal_fn<string> {
    bool operator()(const string& t1, const string& t2) const {
        return !(t1.compare(t2));
    }
};

unordered_map<string, string, hashing_func, key_equal_fn<string> > text2cnt;
unordered_map<string, string, hashing_func, key_equal_fn<string> >::iterator iter;
```

Comment: well, I guess the value type doesn't really matter here. I wanted to use <string, int>, although the cited link uses <string, string>. Either way, the key_equal_fn should be dealing with string and string, because they're the keys from two items in the hash map.

Comment: you mean you want do a fully-specialized template? i will reedit it.